# How to add paging with the paging library in my structure

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

**How to add paging with the paging library in my structure**

I'm looking to put a pagination on my product listings. How do I add paging with paging library 3 in jetpack compose. I took a look at the documentation but I didn't understand. Anyone who can help I appreciate it

My Repository:

```kotlin
package com.example.quitanda.reposittory

import com.example.quitanda.classes.Retrofit

class SearchRepository {
    private val retrofit = Retrofit()
    private val search = retrofit.frutasServices
    // ...
    suspend fun getSearch(userId: String) =
    // This isn't an optimal implementation because it doesn't take into
    // account caching. We'll look at how to improve upon this in the next
        // sections.
        search.getSearch(userId)
}
```

My viewModel:

```kotlin
package com.example.quitanda.models

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.quitanda.reposittory.SearchRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class SearchViewModel:ViewModel() {
    private val searchRepository= SearchRepository()

    private val _searche: MutableStateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())
    val searche: StateFlow<List<ShoppingCart>>
        get() = _searche

    fun buscar(title:String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {

                _searche.value = searchRepository.getSearch(title)

            }catch (e:Exception){
                Log.d("Service error",e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Service:

```kotlin
package com.example.quitanda.models

import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Path

interface Services {
    @GET("category/")
    suspend fun  getFruta(): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/{id}")
    suspend fun getFrutas1(@Path("id") id: Int): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/{id}")
    suspend fun  getVerduras(@Path("id") id:Int): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/{id}")
    suspend fun  getTemperos(@Path("id") id:Int): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("category/busca/{title}")
    suspend fun getSearch(@Path("title") title: String): List<ShoppingCart>

    @GET("product/{id}")
    suspend fun getSingle(@Path("id") id: Int): List<ShoppingCart>
}
```